# Received pushed email from IMAP server

Tags: vb.net, email, push, imap

I am trying to build an application that will receive pushed email from an IMAP server (such as Gmail). I don't want to be constantly fetching the inbox, but instead receive pushed emails. How may I accomplish this and which direction do I need to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## IMAP IDLE - server updates to the client in real time

You may use [`IMAP` with `IDLE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) command.

It will keep single IMAP session open and notify you about new messages.

- Gmail servers support IDLE
- There seems to be a Visual Studio extension supporting IDLE

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh within some interval to check for new emails.
Some sample code in C# here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24535/Email-Client-Application-by-Implementing-Our-Own-S

Comment: The point of getting the emails pushed though is so that I don't have to fetch them within some interval.